# How to use greek letters in fig.caption using RMarkdown?

Tags: latex, r-markdown, caption

This code produces an error when I try to knit a pdf using *RMarkdown* in *RStudio*.

How can I write a greek letter in *fig.caption* as for example $\beta$?

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "SB"
date: "Thursday, January 29, 2015"
output: 
  pdf_document:
  fig_caption: yes
---


```{r var, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="Cars variation rate between year $t$ and $t-1$ for $0 < \beta < 1$"}
plot(cars)
```
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In R, all backslashes inside character strings need to be doubled. `"\\"` becomes `\`.

Try this:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "SB"
date: "Thursday, January 29, 2015"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
---

```{r var, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="Cars variation rate between year $t$ and $t-1$ for $0 < \\beta < 1$"}
plot(cars)
```
````